# I have ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'server' when i enter nvidia-detector

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-settings

```
ubuntu@deeplearn-ubuntu:~$ nvidia-detector 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/nvidia-detector", line 8, in <module>
    a = NvidiaDetection(printonly=True, verbose=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/NvidiaDetector/nvidiadetector.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.getData()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/NvidiaDetector/nvidiadetector.py", line 163, in getData
    driver_version = self.__get_value_from_name(stripped_package_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/NvidiaDetector/nvidiadetector.py", line 92, in __get_value_from_name
    v = int(name)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'server'
```

Comment: Reported upstream: https://github.com/tseliot/ubuntu-drivers-common/issues/46

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is but there is a commit posted at the GitHub link that @JanBlechta posted that worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04. At the time of writing this comment I believe they are still working on the fix for older versions of Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

workaround is to add these lines in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/NvidiaDetector/nvidiadetector.py:

```
--- nvidiadetector.py   2020-08-09 15:54:01.089855652 +0400
+++ /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/NvidiaDetector/nvidiadetector.py 2020-08-09 16:26:15.321390371 +0400
@@ -160,6 +160,8 @@
             # package names can be like "nvidia-173:i386" and we need to
             # extract the driver flavour from the name e.g. "173"
             stripped_package_name = package.name.split('-')[-1].split(':', 1)[0]
+            if not stripped_package_name.isnumeric():
+                stripped_package_name = package.name.split('-')[-2].split('-', -1)[0]
             driver_version = self.__get_value_from_name(stripped_package_name)
 
             try:
```

because one of the packages uses a string suffix after the version number.

Comment: I get the same error after adding these two lines on 18.04. Is there any step I might be missing?

Comment: check stripped_package_name value after this line:
`
stripped_package_name = package.name.split('-')[-1].split(':', 1)[0]
`
and if there is a non-numeric value, fix the split rules

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but get "none" for some reason